# Git merge conflict is not showing which changes to accept toolbar

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I pull something from other branch and conflict occurs in that case sometimes vscode shows me which changes to accept like this image.

[image]

But for some conflict vscode doesn't show this toolbar what to accept. rather it shows string in vscode which mixed up with code. here is screenshot of this problem.

[image]

How can I solve above picture problem?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when cut-and-paste of actual text will do (which it would here). See [ask].

Comment: Meanwhile: this may be an internal conflict due to multiple merge bases, or it may be the result of someone committing the conflicted version, rather than resolving the conflict. To find out, you can run `git merge-base --all <other-branch>` from the command line. I have no idea how (or even *if*) you can find this in Visual Studio more directly.